# Android - How to correctly send an http request by CoroutineScope in a viewModel related to the lifecycle when exiting a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I need to send an http request as soon as the user presses the back button and exits the fragment. I don't want to wait for a response from the server, I just need to shoot to the server. I can't do this in `viewModelScope` because it is related to the fragment's life cycle and it will never happen. I tried to do this in a separate scope like `CoroutineScope (Dispatchers.IO).launch {...}` but the effect is the same the coroutin doesn't execute.
My pseudo code below:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val sendAnalyticsUseCase: SendAnalyticsUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

    ...

    fun sendAnalytics() {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            sendAnalyticsUseCase()
        }
    }

    ...

}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()

    ...

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher
            .addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                    viewModel.sendAnalytics()
                    findNavController().popBackStack()
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For things like that, there is `GlobalScope`

```
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        sendAnalyticsUseCase()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know GlobalScope but it's not recommended, it causes memory leaks. My application is Single Activity Architecture so I can inject viewModel from MainActivity into a Fragment and make an API request on it. But I think I should use WorkManager for this. I don't know which is better :)

Comment: Ok, but I think you still can define CoroutineScope as you tried but not in the view model but in some component/object that lives longer than the view model - e.g. some singleton?

Comment: I found something interesting https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#create-coroutines-data-layer. I think I have a solution. Take a look at the ArticlesRepository class. This is exactly the case for me :)

Comment: Yeah, that's what said :-). Sorry if I didn't explain it properly.

Comment: Don't worry. The goal has been achieved. Thanks again :)